# What is the difference between an AWS service being regional vs Global?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For example EC2 instances are regional.Does that mean we cannot use the applications hosted on that EC2 from other regions?

Answer (score 1):

Applications hosted on an EC2 Instance from one region can be exposed to Public / Internet through Internet Gateway. This way your App even though hosted in say Asia-Pacific Region will be accessible from everywhere.

This is from AWS portal - "Each region is fully isolated and comprised of multiple AZ’s, which are fully isolated partitions of our infrastructure". What this means in the actual Infrastructure (Physical Servers) are isolated from each other from different regions.

The AWS documentation does a pretty good job on explaining these concepts.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/?p=ngi&loc=2

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/?p=ngi&loc=4

Comment: ThankYou Raj for the answer..I am new to the concept of cloud computing .By Your answer does that mean with out an Internet Gateway ,we can access the EC2 resources only with in a region?

Comment: Entire AWS is based on VPC (Virtual Private Cloud) which kind of forms a private boundary for all your resources. Without specifically exposing your resources to public through IGW (Internet Gateways) and NAT it wont be possible to access them on internet

Comment: If you have Internet Gateway attached to your VPC, and with proper routing is set on the Route Table, then your EC2 will be accessible all over the internet(assuming the security groups have all traffic in it's inbound rule).